# Subtracting percentages from Values

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a set of simple tables inputted with basic user information. I know how to display the salary but I am unsure about how to minus 50% of the salary for all employees rounding it to one decimal place.

So far this is my method and how I would round my percentage to 1 d.p but I am unsure how to calculate and subtract the percentage from the salary:

```
**ROUND_ABS, SELECT salary + (salary /100 *1)/1;**
```

This is the table that it refers to:

```
ID  LastName    FirstName   Address          Salary 

1   Hansen      Ola         Timoteivn 10     23.600 
2   Svendson    Tove        Borgvn 23        29.687
3   Pettersen   Kari        Storgt 20        34.762
```

Comment: Is this Oracle? See the [`round()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions169.htm) function. Actual sample data would help. What has HIRE_DATE got to do with it?

Comment: Yes it is Oracle. The sample data is provided in bold and HIRE_DATE is for another section which may also be incorrect which I meant to remove but forgot so apologies. EDIT I have now removed this section

Comment: Part of your issue seems to be with elementary arithmetic. If the salary is in a column `salary` and you must subtract 44% from the salary, the formula is `salary * ( 1 - 44/100 )` - and if `44` is a variable (a column name, etc.) you write that instead of 44. This has nothing to do with programming - or with computer technology of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? As far as I understood, you have to calculate half of the salary and round it to one decimal point.

```
SQL> with test (name, salary) as
  2    (select 'Svenson', 29687.13 from dual union
  3     select 'Pettersen', 34762.47 from dual
  4    )
  5  select name, salary, salary / 2 half, round(salary / 2, 1) rounded_half
  6  from test;

NAME          SALARY       HALF ROUNDED_HALF
--------- ---------- ---------- ------------
Pettersen   34762,47  17381,235      17381,2
Svenson     29687,13  14843,565      14843,6

SQL>
```

Comment: This is on the right track but I know it is possible to do this statement in one line. To simplify I need to try and subtract 50% from a salary and then round it to 1 decimal point. Thank you everyone for the assistance so far.

Comment: "One line" is line #5, with only "ROUND(SALARY / 2, 1)". I intentionally displayed other values so that you could easier follow what's going on, adding piece by piece of information (dividing by 2, rounding it).

Answer (score 0):

If you want 50% salary to be selected right from the query, following should work:

```
SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName, Address, ROUND((Salary/2),1) from Table_Name
```